# Get std::pair member using only standard function in C++03

Tags: c++, c++03

Is there a way, using only C++03 standard functions get a `std::pair` member, i.e. `first` or `second`?

In C++11 I could use `std::get<0>` or `std::get<1>` respectively in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no free function that allows you to retrieve `std::pair::first` and `std::pair::second`. It is, however, trivial to implement:

```
template <std::size_t TI, typename T>
struct get_helper;

template <typename T>
struct get_helper<0, T>
{
    typedef typename T::first_type return_type;

    return_type operator()(T& pair) const
    {
        return pair.first;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct get_helper<1, T>
{
    typedef typename T::second_type return_type;

    return_type operator()(T& pair) const
    {
        return pair.second;
    }
};

template <std::size_t TI, typename T>
typename get_helper<TI, T>::return_type my_get(T& pair)
{
    return get_helper<TI, T>()(pair);
}
```

[**coliru example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f95ccfe05de53a1)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. If you want them, you'll have to make them yourself.